# Is there a more accurate clock for pygame for a rhythm game I'm making

Tags: python, time, pygame

I'm trying to get a series of lines to fall through the screen at **exact** tempo, for example, you input say 120 BPM and the result is the road lines hitting the bottom of the screen at 120 BPM.

I have tried using both `pygame.clock.tick()` and `pygame.time.delay()` (which I heard is more accurate), however when I use these as a clock to blit both the background and the road lines, against a metronome the clock seems very inconsistent.

For making an exact rhythm game which must stay in time for the entire song, is there another way to do this?

```py
#GAMELOOP
while playing==True:
    
    win.blit(bg,(0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            playing = False
    #win.fill(WHITE)

    y1=y1+gameSpeed
    y2=y2+gameSpeed
    y3=y3+gameSpeed
    win.blit(track1,(x,y1))
    win.blit(track2,(x,y2))
    win.blit(track3,(x,y3))
    if y1>=1000:
        y1=-2000
    if y2>=1000:
        y2=-2000
    if y3>=1000:
        y3=-2000
    

    fpsClock.tick(30)
    pygame.display.update()
    
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: [`fpsClock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) returns the number of milliseconds since the previous call. You should use this to determine how far to move your sprites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

120 BPM (which I assume is "Beats Per Minute"), is only a per half-second timing, that's reasonably slow in computer terms.  Most applications repaint the screen at 3600 frame-updates per minute (60Hz).

You can use the `pygame.time` object to return the number of milliseconds since the program started.  This is really useful for timing things in the game:

```
clock = pygame.time.get_ticks()   # time now
```

So immediately on start-up, this time is "0 milliseconds", and grows from there, forever more.

This value can then be used in relative time comparisons.  When you make the `track1` fall, it's possible to update the y-position based on the clock.  One way to do this is to calculate the future millisecond-time at which the `track1` should *next* move:

```
clock = pygame.time.get_ticks() 
track1_move_next_time =  clock + 500    # 500 milliseconds = 120 BPM
```

The repeatedly check that time until it's in the past.  *Then* move the `track1`:

```
# In the Main Loop:

clock = pygame.time.get_ticks() 

# ...

if ( clock > track1_move_next_time ):      # is it time to move?
    y1 += pixels_per_tick                  # move it 
    track1_move_next_time =  clock + 500   # set next move time
```